# Extract URL Parameter using Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How can I extract the URL parameter "kw" from this URL using an Excel formula?

```
http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&amp;ai=CJUQ7zvAbVdK_CrHSsQf6iIHYD7zV59kHvJfs5LABpuWU_AMIABABKANgofiHgGygAbz01eADyAEBqQK8TgDDlm9-PqoEKE_QrRjDXKCZneohUov47wCTKVWTFGDo-TbcFZnV3yZ1YGhvXWUb_WuIBgGAB6yLqh-QBwOoB6a-G9gHAQ&amp;ohost=www.google.com.ar&amp;cid=5GhbrxlB07mO7bZOlKEDRYCN1cvrdfvVgL6nRn6sDtpHjLQ&amp;sig=AOD64_1lIeXRqqfwLyHYFCfMWeYn0n0N6Q&amp;rct=j&amp;q=&amp;ved=0CBkQ0Qw&amp;adurl=http://segurosendirecto.com.ar/cotizador-de-seguros-auto?kw=san%2520cristobal%2520seguros
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the URL in cell **A1**, use:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("kw=",A1)+3,9999)
```

[image]

and if you want to include the ***wk=***, just drop the `+3` from the formula.

Comment: not working in excel 2010, says formula contains an error